# Change border color on textarea validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Need to make a custom error effect on validation of `textarea`. 
Tries to do it with little script, which changes `errorClass`, maybe I'm doing something wrong or misunderstood.

```
$('#message').validate({ errorClass:'error'});
```

Error should look like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAsBj.png

By now it looks default: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTwzA.png

There is that I've got: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12816/)

Comment: What validation library are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see from your example, you're using html5 validation. To style those use the following `pseudo selector`:

```
input:focus:invalid, textarea:focus:invalid{
    border-color: red !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px red;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px red;
}
```

`:focus` is necessary for when you ONLY want to validate when user is typing.

Check your updated example here: https://jsfiddle.net/2436ey01/

For adding custom messages you can customize the built in validation using javascript:

```
var message = document.querySelector('textarea#message');

message.oninvalid = function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity("");
    if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("You shall not pass!");
    }
};
```

Here an example: https://jsfiddle.net/z73gtr6s/

Comment: Dat works only for `#name` and `#email`. Doesn't works for textarea.

Comment: Sorry modified my answer. I added the textarea:focus:invalid to the selector

Comment: Now it works! Nice one and pretty easy. Could I realise a error text under 'textarea' with same way?

Comment: I added some code for customizing the text under textarea

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you. As i **do not know** what library you using, still can help you with some way.

**JS/JQuery Code**

```
$('.submit').click(function(){
    var content = $('textarea').text();
    if(content == "")
    {
        $('textarea').addClass('redBorder');
    }
    else
    {
        $('textarea').removeClass('redBorder');
    }
});
```

[Working:Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12817/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a good (easy to use) library to add inline error messages- 
You can use [webshim](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html), working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42w4w6oL/1/) for your example (without css)

js:

```
webshim.setOptions('forms', {
    lazyCustomMessages: true
});

//start polyfilling
webshim.polyfill('forms');
```

I used the inline validation as seen here:

http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/forms.html#UI-replaceValidationUI

Comment: Good option. But when I typed 'name' and 'email' and pressed submit, there is still default effect: http://i.imgur.com/pkGS0WH.png 

It disappears when I make 'textarea' inactive.

Comment: @QuackZilla ahh, I used wrong jsfiddle link- I updated answer with correct link: https://jsfiddle.net/42w4w6oL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are a couple of issues:

1. You don't have an `.error` class defined in your CSS - which might be something like `#message.error` and have the `border: 1px solid red` or what ever.
2. Looks like there is an error in the console that comes through as `validates` is not a function, meaning that you have wrong dependencies so check to see what libraries you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
.touch #message:focus {
box-shadow: none;
border-color: #383838; 
}
```

comment this